# Rails 4 - How to use helper text in an associated partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, helper

I'm trying to figure out how to access a helper method from a view in an associated scaffold

I have models called Project and Ethic. The associations are:

```
Project has_many :ethics
Ethic belongs_to :project
```

In my ethics helper, I have:

```
module EthicsHelper
    def text_for_subcategory(category)
      if category == 'Risk of harm'
            [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
        elsif category == 'Informed consent'
            ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
        elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
            ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
        elsif category == 'Deceptive practices' 
            ["Feasibility"] 
        else category == 'Right to withdraw'    
            ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] 
       end
    end  

end
```

Then in my projects view folder, I have a partial called _ethics.html.erb which has:

```
<% @project.ethics.each do | project_ethics_issue | %>
                       <strong>ETHICS CONSIDERATION: <%= project_ethics_issue.text_for_subcategory(@category) %></strong>
                        <%= project_ethics_issue.considerations %>

                    <% end %>
```

In my projects controller, I have tried:

```
  include EthicsHelper
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `text_for_subcategory' for #<Ethic:0x007fedc57b7b58>
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `_ethics.html.erb`, you only modify this code as:

```
<% @project.ethics.each do | project_ethics_issue | %>
  <strong>ETHICS CONSIDERATION: <%= text_for_subcategory(@category).join(",") %></strong>
  <%= project_ethics_issue.considerations %>
<% end %>
```

Update:

I saw in your file `ethics_helper.rb`, it seems your logic code is not correct.

```
module EthicsHelper
  def text_for_subcategory(category)
    if category == 'Risk of harm'
        [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
    elsif category == 'Informed consent'
        ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
    elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
        ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
    elsif category == 'Deceptive practices' 
        ["Feasibility"] 
    elsif category == 'Right to withdraw'    
        ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] 
    else
        []
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: thanks @Khanh - that worked to display the content of the helper, but it displays the text inside [" "]. I can't remove those tags from the helper because I then get an error in displaying the form.

Comment: Because you put your text in `array`, so if you want to display text as `Explanation of research,Explanation of participant's role in research`, you only write as:

`text_for_subcategory(@category).join(",")`

Comment: there is only one thing in the array. The content of the array displays properly in the form, but in the show partial, it displays inside [" "]. I just want to show the content of the selected element of the array (which in this case, is the only thing in the array. I don't want the [" "] to be displayed

Comment: @Mel i've just updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: Hi - but I don't want to join two elements from the array. I just don't want to display the [" "] that are currently displayed in the show partial. It currently displays as: ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] . I want: Right to withdraw from participation in the project

Comment: @Mel you can use `join(",")` to convert `array` to `string` as you want. 
For example:  `["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"].join(",")` will be `Right to withdraw from participation in the project`. And in this case `[" "].join(",")` will be `" "`. And you can use method `strip` to remove this `blank`.

Comment: So how do I put strip into that sequence? Also, if the relevant text to display is part of an array that has more than one item, I only want to display the one that is selected, so does strip also remove the other options from the display?

Comment: @Mel `strip` method doesn't remove other options, it only remove `trailing whitespace`, you can refer `strip` method at: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip

Comment: Thanks. I think I need a different approach to this problem. Thanks anyway for your help.